# Memory leak in program with class inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

Following is the code snippet:

```
class Create_size_one_Nodes  : public Adjacency_list
{
public:
    Create_size_one_Nodes()
    {
        nodes_hashtable = NULL;                 
        //adds the nodes present in the graph to the hashtable
        create_nodes_hashtable();   
    }

    ~Create_size_one_Nodes()
    {
        delete(nodes_hashtable);
        nodes_hashtable = NULL;
        count_size_one_nodes_created = 0;
    }
};

class Adjacency_list
{
protected :
//create a hash table that collects the nodes already created
//the key of the hashtable is the start value of the node
//the end of the node acts as the unique object indentifier
Hashtable *nodes_hashtable;

//given the hashtable,updates the values in the hashtable
void create_nodes_hashtable();
public :

//creates the adjacency list
Adjacency_list()
{   
    nodes_hashtable = NULL;

}

//after the adjcency list has been created
//clears the contents of the adjacency list
~Adjacency_list()
{
    delete(nodes_hashtable);
    nodes_hashtable = NULL;
}
};

//given the hashtable,updates the values in the hashtable
void Adjacency_list ::  create_nodes_hashtable()
{
//remove the pointer from the previous set position
nodes_hashtable = new(std::nothrow) Hashtable(WINDOW_LENGTH *HASHTABLE_SCALING_FACTOR);

  //check :if the hashtable has been created
  if(NULL == nodes_hashtable)
  {
    string error_message = "void Adjacency_list ::  create_nodes_hashtable() , the hash table hasnot been created";
    cerr<<error_message<<endl;
  }

for(unsigned int i = 0;i< no_of_valid_nodes ;i++)
{       
    //normalising the key ,so that the key lies within the range of the hashtable
    int key = get_nodes_hashtablekey(node_start[i],node_end[i]);
    (*nodes_hashtable).add_element(key,node_end[i],i);
}
```

}

[update]:

```
class Hashtable
{

private :

//counts the number of elements added into the hashtable
unsigned int count_elements_added;

//counts the number of elements removed from the hashtable
unsigned int count_elements_removed;

//counts the number of elements present in the hashtable
unsigned int count_elements_present;

//sets the size of the hashtable
unsigned int hashtable_size;

//the data structure (vector) that contains the objects
//the position on the hastable is defined by 2 keys
//one the position in the array of the hashtable : the start of the node is used
//the second is the first element in the pair present in the hash table //end of the node is used
std :: vector< std :: vector<std :: pair<int,int> > > hashtable;

//intialize the hashtable
void intialize_hashtable();

//checks whether the hashtable is corrupted or not
//returns true,if the hashtable is corrupted
//else returns false
bool is_corrupt();

public :

Hashtable()
{
    hashtable_size = DEFAULT_HASHTABLE_SIZE;
    hashtable.clear();
    intialize_hashtable();

    //counts the number of elements added into the hashtable
    count_elements_added = 0;

    //counts the number of elements removed from the hashtable
    count_elements_removed = 0;

    //counts the number of elements present in the hashtable
    count_elements_present = 0;
};

Hashtable(int hash_table_size)
{
    hashtable.clear();
    hashtable_size = hash_table_size;
    intialize_hashtable();

    //counts the number of elements added into the hashtable
    count_elements_added = 0;

    //counts the number of elements removed from the hashtable
    count_elements_removed = 0;

    //counts the number of elements present in the hashtable
    count_elements_present = 0;
};

//add elemnet to the hashtable
void add_element(int key,int object_identifier,int object_info);

//given the key and the object identifier
//returns the object info
int get_element(int key,int object_identifier);

//delete the element from the hashtable
void remove_element(int key,int object_identifier);

//prints the contents of the hashtable
void print();

~Hashtable()
{
    hashtable_size = 0;
    hashtable.clear();

    //counts the number of elements added into the hashtable
    count_elements_added = 0;

    //counts the number of elements removed from the hashtable
    count_elements_removed = 0;

    //counts the number of elements present in the hashtable
    count_elements_present = 0;

};
};
```

The object of create_size_one_nodes is created in main.
But when it goes out of scope, memory is not freed.

```
Create_size_one_Nodes create_size_one_Nodes_object;
create_size_one_Nodes_object.create_nodes_size_one();
```

I am not able to delete the memory in delete(nodes_hastable).
valgrid points out leak in the code.
the vakgrind output is:

```
==16451== 27,692 (28 direct, 27,664 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 7
==16451==    at 0x402A208: operator new(unsigned int, std::nothrow_t const&) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==16451==    by 0x80E05FF: Adjacency_list::create_nodes_hashtable() (adjacency_list.cpp:75)
```

Please guide me on how to remove this memory leak

Comment: Show more code, especially `create_nodes_hashtable()`. What's the type of `node_hastables` ?

Comment: your both `constructor` and `destructor` are private. I am surprised how you are creating object of `Create_size_one_Nodes` from outside of class.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I agree. I have a feeling that nodes_hashtable is simply a pointer to an array, and it isn't iterating through and deleting any allocated memory in that array.

Comment: `~Adjacency_list()` should be virtual...

Comment: And what is `Hashtable` ?

Comment: *How* is create_size_one_nodes created in the main? On stack? On heap but released through a pointer of Adjacency_list()? @Jarod42 is right - first of all you have to make the destructor virtual. **Always** make a destructor virtual if you intend to inherit the class. If the class isn't meant to be inherited then you could make its constructor private (so no inheriting class can be constructed) and add a factory function (friend or static) to the class.

Comment: added the relevant code

Comment: @ierceg: made the changes as asked, it didnt sort out the problem.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: added the relevant code.

Comment: @rajenpandit: made the necessary changes to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to supply some extra information.

What type is nodes_hashtable? 
The creat_nodes_hashtable method.

There could be several things wrong but without more info it's impossible to know:

a) nodes_hashtable is really an array and the correct way to dealocate would be `delete[] nodes_hashtable;`

b) create_nodes_hashtable is actually doing more allocation that we don't know about, or is allocating stuff and not assigning it to nodes_hashtable or whatever.

Regards,
 V. Seguí

Comment: I tried delete[] nodes_hashtable. It still doesn't clear the memory.Valgrind still indicates memory leak.

Comment: its added data into the hashtable, as indicated in the updated code.

Comment: You will need to supply a self contained test case, that is, something that can be compiled and executed which showcases the bug with minimal code (e.g no other code that does not serve to proof the point). I've often found that trying to reproduce bugs with minimal code leads to finding them. OTOH as somebody has suggested you should be declaring your destructors virtual (90% of the cases it's what you want).

Comment: I made the base class destructor virtual, it doesn't help.

Comment: Supply a compilable test case, without more information about how your objects are interacting it's impossible to know where the leak is (for instance are you really deleting the Adjacency_list object you are creating?).

Comment: no i am not deleting the adjacency_list object, it should go out of scope itself. Its destructor is being called. I checked that.

Comment: the code is almost 70K lines of code. so cant add it here.

Comment: You should make a small, self contained, reproducible test that illustrates the problem and post that.

Answer (score 0):

- Make the base class destructor as Virtual
- you don't actually need to delete nodes_hashtable here as it is allocated only when create_nodes_hashtable() function is called , i.e do it inside Create_size_one_Nodes destructor

  `//after the adjcency list has been created
  //clears the contents of the adjacency list
  ~Adjacency_list()
  {
     /* delete here is not required as create_nodes_hashtable() is not called inside this class. Ideally whoever allocated memory should free.But No harm if you keep */
      delete(nodes_hashtable);

      nodes_hashtable = NULL;
  }`

Comment: :made the relevant changes to the code. it hasnt helped

Comment: I just checked your hashtable definition, it is vector of vector conaining pair, I am not sure whether hashtable.clear() will call clear() on the internal vector also.

Comment: If possible you can post which part of program reports memory leak in valgrind